# Error with has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot modify association 'Business#placements' because the source reflection class 'Placement' is associated to 'Employee' via :has_many.
```

My models look as follows:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :placements

class Placement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :business

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :placements, through: :employees
```

The error occurs when I call

```
@employee.votes.create!(phone_id: 35435656)
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

delete belongs_to :business from your Placement model:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :placements

class Placement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :placements, through: :employees
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete

```
belongs_to :business
```

from Placement

It belongs to business through the employee association, so you just have to have belongs_to employee.

Answer (score 0):

Employee has many placements, Placement belongs to Employee and Business has many placements through Employee. So Business is associated with Placement through Employee where Placement itself belongs to Employee. Hence, you just need to delete

```
belongs_to :business
```

from Placement.

Answer (score 0):

In association,

```
Business model has_many :placements, through: :employees
```

and

```
Employes belongs_to :business
```

So we no need belongs_to :business in Placement Model